# Error 424 Object Required When attempting to use ActiveCell in VBA

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I work in education and I am trying to automatically allocate students to subject choices based on two defining factors: CLV (Curriculum Level) and their term of enrolment.

I have coded the `VBA` using a series of `if then else` statements which I want to be triggered by the selection of a variable from a data validation list to write values in the appropriate corresponding cells (using `activecell.offset`).

My first VBA coding test only required one "if" dependent on the activecell and it worked and was triggered directly from within the VBA editor, as I was unsure of how to get it to trigger from the data validation list selection.

As soon as I attempted to put in two other variables offset from the activecell using `And` commands, however, it returned an `Error 424 Object Required` statement and I'm not sure why.

I have included a link to the workbook and also posted the code below.  Any help appreciated!
[Curriculum Variations File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53138339/Curriculum%20Variations.xlsm)

```
Sub StandardEntry()
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActivCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 1" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 7" Then
        CLV7Term1
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 2" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 7" Then
        CLV7Term2
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 3" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 7" Then
        CLV7Term3
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 4" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 7" Then
        CLV7Term4
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 1" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 8" Then
        CLV8Term1
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 2" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 8" Then
        CLV8Term2
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 3" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 8" Then
        CLV8Term3
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 4" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 8" Then
        CLV8Term4
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 1" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 9" Then
        CLV9Term1
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 2" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 9" Then
        CLV9Term2
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 3" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 9" Then
        CLV9Term3
    Else
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Term 4" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).Value = "CLV 9" Then
        CLV9Term4
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: You would get better response if you posted the code you've tried.

Comment: Ok.  I did include a link to the file but I've also now edited and included the code in the post. Thanks for commenting.

Comment: You have a typo - `ActivCell` - on the first `If` statement.  Put `Option Explicit` at the top of all your modules to avoid this type of problem.

Comment: @Comintern Thanks!  I don't know what I hadn't spotted that earlier.  I guess that's what happens when you stare at a screen too long.  The code now works.  I **really** appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that all I needed was an extra "e" on "ActivCell" in the first if statement.  Ahh - the little things in life!  Thanks @Comintern for your editing assistance!  Glad I was already on the right track.